# Does taking the special requirements IELTS damage a Canada immigration case?

Tags: immigration, canada

I'm a non-native English speaker applying for immigration to Canada. I'm required to the take general IELTS test. It costs $210 in my country. I suffer from cerebral palsy, my writing speed is slow, my handwriting is bad.

English tests are easy. At university, I got 95/100 in advanced English course. I used to finish my tests before other students because the questions were silly, and I didn't have to use scratch paper for essays. I was able to write everything directly on the test paper, which gave me huge advantage.

It has been two years since my last English course, so my English skills have decreased a bit. I don't know if I can do the same things when taking the IELTS. I might need more time to finish it. If I take any risk and fail due to time or my handwriting, it means I'll have to pay another $200.

But if I apply for the [special requirements test](https://www.ielts.org/book-a-test/special-requirements), it would take 2 to 3 month to get an approval before I can take the test. Moreover, I'm afraid that by taking that test, I might damage my immigration application.

Being labeled a disabled person already damages my chances. Being labeled a disabled person who can't write English without special tools kills my chances. I don't need special tools, I just need more time, to finish it and to try and make my handwriting prettier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the IELTS test with special requirements in December 2017  because I am hearing impaired. I can confirm that although the British Council (where I took the test) granted my special request and conducted the test, the IELTS score card has no mention of this. It's as if I took the test normally without any special requirements.

Yes, you would need to inform them 2-3 months in advance so that they can arrange the materials, but it was well worth it as I sailed through the exam in a single attempt. This is important as it will save you time (and money). I see a lot of people (at least from India) struggling to clear the exam in a single attempt.

Therefore, as @Dipen Shah says, all IRCC care about is your IELTS score and not how you took the test.

All the best!

Answer (score 2):

> Being labeled a disabled person already damages my chances

Why do you feel that this is the case? (Its not) Let me tell you that Canada is a very strong supporter of equal rights for the ones having special requirements.

Also when you apply for Permanent Residence, all they care about is your IELTS score and not how you took it.

I will suggest that if the special requirements test increases your chances of getting good bands in the exam, you should definitely give the test that way.

With your level of English, I would say you will most definitely get good bands.

Good luck!